# Jekyll - how to auto regenerate after menu.yaml changes?

Tags: yaml, jekyll, reload

When I am developing with Jekyll, this is my watch task:

```
"watch": "bundle exec jekyll serve --incremental --config _config.yml",
```

Which works fine for normal page editing. However if I change a menu entry in something like `_data/menu.yaml` technically **all** pages would need to be regenerated. (Since all contain that menu…), yet only a few files get regenerated (and I even have no clue according what rules…).

```
  Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
  Regenerating: 1 file(s) changed at 2017-12-21 10:46:54 

  Filename                                     | Count | Bytes | …
  ---------------------------------------------+-------+-------+-…
  feed.xml                                     |     1 | 2.54K | …
  sitemap.xml                                  |     1 | 2.80K | …
  css/main.sass                                |     1 | 0.38K | …
  _posts/2017-07-07-a-fancy-July-post.md/      |     1 | 0.16K | …
  _posts/2017-11-15-last-week-today.md/        |     1 | 0.00K | …
  _posts/2017-10-20-late-October-is-here.md/   |     1 | 0.00K | …

  ...done in 2.074543555 seconds.
```

Thus, all the time I have to stop, clean (`rm -rf _site`) and then fully build/start the watch again, to have an updated menu on the pages.

**Is there a better way to do this? Am I missing some configuration?**

Comment: Try with jekyll serve --force_polling

Comment: @marcanuy `--force_polling` [is a cure](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/2926#issuecomment-55629052) when you are running out of [file handles aka 'inodes'](https://serverfault.com/questions/707490/how-to-determine-which-processes-have-most-inodes-opened) for regular file watching. This is not the cause of trouble here. Number of total files is rather small. (And I sorted this kind of error on a different occasion, when a different tool ran out of them...) The symptoms would afaik also be different ("watch not triggered", rather than "dependencies ignored").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--incremental` is an experimental (unfinished) feature. Remove it from your task, as well as `--config` that is set to default, thus useless.

`"watch": "bundle exec jekyll serve",` will do the trick.

Comment: A slightler 'leaner' way is to stick with `--incremental` and `touch` the file(s), that references the yaml-File, i.e. `touch _includes/header.html`